# How to get request headers cookie in rails 5 api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

Im trying to get the cookies, from the controller, with `puts request.headers['Cookie']` and nothing is showing in my terminal.

My see the details in chrome tools:

[image]

How to get the cookie, please?

Edit

[See gist for header response](https://gist.github.com/SylarRuby/d56ac27ee51d23957f517f3947313c75).

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
request.headers["Cookie"]
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-headers

Comment: Tried that but same thing. That cook is an httponly cookie so hope that shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: please print `request.headers` and share result

Comment: It's massive so still need it?

Answer (score 1):

just use cookies

```
puts cookies[:name]
```